Factorization to sparse matrices
$\newcommand{\lrank}{\operatorname{lrank}}$
$\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}$
Given a matrix $A$, we can define its Hamming weight, $w(A)$, as the number of non-zero elements in it.
Now, given a matrix $A$, we define $\lrank'(A) = \min_{BC = A} w(B)w(C)$.
We now look at $\lrank(A) = \sqrt{\frac{\lrank'(A)}{nm}}$ (where $A$ is an $n \times m$ matrix).
Note that if instead of only counting non-zero elements we counted all values, then instead of $\lrank$ we get the usual $\rank$, due to its characterization as the minimal $k$ for which $A$ can be factored to an $n \times k$ matrix times a $k \times m$ one.
What is known about this $\lrank$ (or $\lrank'$, or a differently scaled version)? Is there any literature about it?
We are working over a finite field, if it is relevant.
It can be noted that if we were working over the two element boolean algebra then $\rank$ is the number of rectangles in an optimal cover and $\lrank$ is closely linked, weighting the rectangles by their size.
